# session is not working in codeiginiter framework

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

I am new to Codeigniter. I am following https://www.webslesson.info/2018/10/user-registration-and-login-system-in-codeigniter-3.html as a tutorial for my project to make registration and login page using `codeiginiter`.

Everything is fine but the session is not working to my need.

**What I Want:-**

**non logged in user also see the private area which is only seen by logged in user.**

Here is my code:

**login.php controller**

```
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if ($this->session->userdata('hospital_email')) {
            redirect('private_area');
        }
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('encryption');
        $this->load->model('login_model');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('view/login');
    }

    function validation()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('hospital_email', 'Email Address', 'required|trim|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Password', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $result = $this->login_model->can_login($this->input->post('hospital_email'), $this->input->post('pass'));
            if ($result == '') {
                redirect('private_area');
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $result);
                redirect('view/login');
            }
        } else {
            $this->index();
        }
    }
}
```

**login_model.php model file**

```
class Login_model extends CI_Model
{
    function can_login($email, $password)
    {
        $this->db->where('hospital_email', $email);
        $query = $this->db->get('hospital');
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                if ($row->is_email_verified == 'yes') {
                    $store_password = $this->encryption->decrypt($row->pass);
                    if ($password == $store_password) {
                        $this->session->set_userdata('hospital_email', $row->hospital_email);
                    } else {
                        return 'Wrong Password';
                    }
                } else {
                    return 'First verified your email address';
                }
            }
        } else {
            return 'Wrong Email Address';
        }
    }
}
```

**private_area.php controller**

```
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Private_area extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if (!$this->session->userdata('hospital_email')) {
            redirect('view/login');
        }
    }

    function index()
    {
        redirect('view/private_area');
    }

    function logout()
    {
        $data = $this->session->all_userdata();
        foreach ($data as $row => $rows_value) {
            $this->session->unset_userdata($row);
        }
        redirect('login');
    }
}
```

**private_area.php view file**

```
echo '<br /><br /><br /><h1 align="center">Welcome User</h1>';
echo '<p align="center"><a href="' . base_url() . 'private_area/logout">Logout</a></p>';
```

Comment: What is "not working"? You will need to provide more details.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw non logged in user also see the private area which is only seen by logged in user.

Comment: So how much of this code varies from what was provided from the tutorial? If the session for "hospital_email" is not set, then a person cannot access the "Private" controller and is redirected to the login page... So you need to explain your issue in more detail

Comment: It sounds like the session is created and still valid.

Comment: And the big question... Did you set up the code exactly as per the Tutorial and test it before fiddling with it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there is another way ,

**how to check value of session is exists or not.**

put this code in the top of `private_area.php` view file:-

```
<?php
 $hospitalSession = $this->session->userdata('hospital_email');
if($hospitalSession['hospital_email']==''){
  redirect('Controller/method_name');   
}

 echo '<br /><br /><br /><h1 align="center">Welcome '.$user.'</h1>';
 echo '<p align="center"><a href="private_area/logout">Logout</a></p>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying those tutorial and nothing errors happen. I don't know what you mean because you didn't provide more detail. But I have simple solution about how to check value of session. 
Change function index() of `Private_area.php` like this

```
$data['user'] = $this->session->userdata('hospital_email');
$this->load->view('private_area', $data);
```

And in your View `private_area.php`

```
<?php
    echo '<br /><br /><br /><h1 align="center">Welcome '.$user.'</h1>';
    echo '<p align="center"><a href="private_area/logout">Logout</a></p>';
?>
```